# How can you use sockets to create platform-independent mutexes?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm looking to create an API for platform-independent mutexes (in Java, though the language isn't really important). I have read that using sockets is a good strategy to do this.

How can you achieve this? How do you avoid the sleeping barber problem?

I'm open to not using sockets... basically I just want to create a platform-independent mutexing protocol.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about **distributed mutexes**. Platform-independent usually means "portable" - being able to work on various hardware  under different operating systems.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I'm not looking for a distributed mutex solution... I'm looking for a way that isn't making native calls to OS-specific mutexing services. It'd be exclusive to the machine on which the process is running.

Comment: Hmm, socket system calls go into the same OS kernel, and inside those calls same lock primitives are used to synchronize access, so I fail to see the point here.